# CoreTypes bundle

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, core-services

In the core types bundle you got a whole bunch of nice icons for all the Macs and iPods etc. that are out there.

The finder can show them in the sidebar when you click on a shared device, like my mac mini server.

I was wondering whether there was an Mac App Store allowed way of accessing these icons, as they are apple copyrighted and I do not know whether I can access them simply through NSImage +imageNamed:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSWorkspace`’s `-iconForFileType:`; e.g.:

```
[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace iconForFileType:@"com.apple.ipad-2-white"];
```

I’m not sure how compatible with the Mac App Store guidelines that is, though.

Comment: It's a public API that doesn't really do anything interesting. Should be fine barring any weird oversensitive sandbox bugs (which, granted, do happen).